# Navigating through HATEOAS with Spring client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hateoas

We have an API which uses Spring JPA and provides access to some data in our database via REST. This API is exposed in a Hateoas fashion (we are using the Spring implementation).

We are now considering whether stick with this approach or code s=our own REST interface manually. Now, I have read a lot of articles about HATEOAS but I am not sure what's the big advantage of using it. Sure, I understand that I can navigate through it using links but I still have to know about the existence of the links at each level, right?

To illustrate my problem, let's say that I have the following structure:

```
server.com/
- /store
- /users/

server.com/users
- /managers/
- /other/

server.com/managers
- list of entities with ids
```

I want to consume this API and get all 'manager' entities (located under `server.com/users/managers`)

What is the correct way to do so when using Spring boot links?

Option one:

```
  RequestEntity<Void> request = RequestEntity.get("server.com/users/managers").accept(HAL_JSON).build();
  final Resource<Manager> managers = restTemplate.exchange(request, new ResourcesType<Manager>() {
        }).getBody();
```

Option two:

```
   // global endpoint
   RequestEntity<Void> request = RequestEntity.get("server.com").accept(HAL_JSON).build();
   final Resource<Object> rootLinks = restTemplate.exchange(request, new ResourceType<Object>() {
        }).getBody();

    Links links = new Links(rootLinks.getLinks());
    final Link userLink = links.getLink("users").expand();

    // users endpoint
    request = RequestEntity.get(URI.create(userLink.getHref())).accept(HAL_JSON).build();
    final Resource<Object> managerLinks = restTemplate.exchange(request, new ResourceType<Object>() {
        }).getBody();

    links = new Links(managerLinks.getLinks());
    final Link managerLink = links.getLink("managers").expand();

    // managers endpoint
    request = RequestEntity.get(URI.create(managerLink.getHref())).accept(HAL_JSON).build();
    final Resources<Manager> resourceAccounts = restTemplate.exchange(request, new ResourcesType<Manager>() {
        }).getBody();
```

The first option one seems straightforward and I can get all entities with single request. However, I fail to see hot Hateoas is beneficial if I just use this approach. Spring documentation states, that using hardcoded links is not recommended.

The second approach seems to be more in the Hateoas fashion but it creates three requests just to get to the resource which location I already know. That doesn't seem right either.

I know it's probably a dummy question but can somebody explain me what is the great idea behind Hateoas that I am clearly missing?

Comment: I don't see the point, if you need to know that "managers" is a sub-path of "users" ("users/managers"). I think instead you should expose a link directly to "users/managers" (and all other frequently used resources) from the root ("global") endpoint. This way you could re-arrange URLs (ie. "staff/managers") without changing the client. As a colleague used to say: "Think less about the URL structure, focus more on the *resource types*".

Comment: So, the point of Hateoas is to help with navigation when you don't know anything about the API? This API is mainly accessed programatically with other services in our system (no human interaction involved). I guess that Hateoas has no usage here then... But you always have to know at least something about the structure right? I just feel that I am missing the point of Hateoas at all

Comment: It's still useful here. REST APIs are normally not for (direct) human consumption. You definitively need to know something about the API. The point is, what you need to know is the resource types and their relationships, rather than their URL structure. I'm no expert though, that's why I don't attempt to answer your question just yet. ;-)

Comment: Why you woudn't use _*spring traverson*_??

Comment: @Raca Yeah, I just found the Traverson - it seems neat. It still executes three http requests underneath though, doesn't it?

Comment: @Smajl i'm not sure :/

Comment: Here is a good answer: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/220806/215307

Answer (score 0):

With HATEOAS server can guide a client through provided links. A contract between server and client is link's relation type and media type. A server can, by providing or not providing links on same resource representation, give client information if a resource is in a state where editing is enabled or not enabled or if a user is authorized for some operation on the resource and so on. A server can change URLs without breaking a contract.

Comment: I already know that. My question is: "How is this beneficial if you are accessing the server programatically and you already know the target uri?? You still have to know at least the 'rel' string. I just don't see how this helps me with anything

Comment: If you control a server and a client then you know URL for some resource but you don't know other information that server can give by providing or not providing links. If server side is out of you control than a resource URL can change and that will break your client.

If you need performance optimization, you can, as @haraldK wrote, "...expose a link directly to "users/managers" (and all other frequently used resources) from the root ("global") endpoint."